# Transferring data from json model to array

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

Is it possible to keep both int and string values ​​in an array? I need help with this.I pulled the data from JSON API. But I couldn't transfer some variables to arrays.

My model is :

```
struct Input: Codable {
    let name: String
    let species: Species
    let gender: Gender
    let house, dateOfBirth: String
    let yearOfBirth: YearOfBirth
    let ancestry, eyeColour, hairColour: String
    let wand: Wand
    let patronus: String
    let hogwartsStudent, hogwartsStaff: Bool
    let actor: String
    let alive: Bool
    let image: String
}



enum YearOfBirth: Codable {
    case integer(Int)
    case string(String)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
            self = .integer(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(YearOfBirth.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for YearOfBirth"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .integer(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .string(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        }
    }
}
```

When I get the yearOfBirth to a String or Integer array, it given error **Cannot convert value of type 'YearOfBirth' to expected argument type 'String'**

Printing yearOfBirth :

```
integer(1980)
integer(1979)
integer(1980)
integer(1980)
integer(1925)
integer(1977)
string("")
integer(1960)
```

Comment: You need to declare your array as [YearOfBirth] but I think this is a bad design. The yearOfBirth property should be an optional Int that is nil of no year ws given in the json.

Comment: You could also map your array of YearOfBirth to an array of Int, `let array: [Int] = [YearOfBirth.integer(3), YearOfBirth.integer(4), YearOfBirth.string("")].compactMap { if case .integer(let value) = $0 { return value } return nil }
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **are** keeping both `Int` and `String` values ​​in an array.

To retrieve them, assuming you have `let years = [YearOfBirth]`:

```
for year in years {
    switch year {
        case .string(let text): print(text) // You can handle texts here
        case .integer(let number): print(number) // You can handle numbers here
    }
}
```

Also, you can convert all to an array of integers like:

```
let numbers: [Int] = years.compactMap { if case .integer(let number) = $0 { return number } else { return nil } }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the value for `yearOfBirth` is only `Int` or empty `String` I'd recommend to use a wrapper struct rather than an enum with associated types and declare the value as optional `Int`

```
struct YearOfBirth: Codable {
    let year : Int?
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let integerValue = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
            year = integerValue
        } else if let stringValue = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            year = Int(stringValue)
        } else {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(YearOfBirth.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for YearOfBirth"))
        }
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encode(year)
    }
}
```

I would ask the owner of the service to refactor the design to send consistent data. Sending an empty string as *integer-nil-value* is ridiculous.